# Nesting dictionary algorithm

Tags: python, data-structures

Suppose I have the following dictionary:

```py
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'c.1': 3, 'd': 4, 'd.1': 5, 'd.1.2': 6}
```

I wish to write an algorithm which outputs the following:

```py
{
    "a": 0,
    "b": 1,
    "c": {
        "c": 2,
        "c.1": 3
    },
    "d":{
        "d": 4,
        "d.1": {
            "d.1": 5,
            "d.1.2": 6
        }
    }
}
```

Note how the names are repeated inside the dictionary. And some have variable level of nesting (eg. `"d"`).

I was wondering how you would go about doing this, or if there is a python library for this? I know you'd have to use recursion for something like this, but my recursion skills are quite poor. Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: With the `"d.1": { "d.1": 5,` bit, this is at least not the usual "dot notation to nested dict" drill...

Comment: What should be the output if the input is `{'b.2.4': 7}`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 in my usecase, `b.2.4` would not appear if `b.2` does not exist already. Right now I am manually creating the second dictionary because it's small enough. I was hoping to automate it. @tobias_k what is the "dot notation to nested dict" drill? It might be the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive function for this or just a loop. The tricky part is wrapping existing values into dictionaries if further child nodes have to be added below them.

```
def nested(d):
    res = {}
    for key, val in d.items():
        t = res
        # descend deeper into the nested dict
        for x in [key[:i] for i, c in enumerate(key) if c == "."]:
            if x in t and not isinstance(t[x], dict):
                # wrap leaf value into another dict
                t[x] = {x: t[x]}
            t = t.setdefault(x, {})
        # add actual key to nested dict
        if key in t:
            # already exists, go one level deeper
            t[key][key] = val
        else:
            t[key] = val
    return res
```

Your example:

```
d = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'c.1': 3, 'd': 4, 'd.1': 5, 'd.1.2': 6}
print(nested(d))
# {'a': 0,
#  'b': 1,
#  'c': {'c': 2, 'c.1': 3},
#  'd': {'d': 4, 'd.1': {'d.1': 5, 'd.1.2': 6}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Nesting dictionary **algorithm**  ...
> how you would go about doing this,

- sort the dictionary items
- group the result by index 0 of the keys (first item in the tuples)
- iterate over the groups

  - if there are is than one item in a group make a key for the group and add the group items as the values.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly shorter recursion approach with `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'c.1': 3, 'd': 4, 'd.1': 5, 'd.1.2': 6}
def group(d, p = []):
  _d, r = defaultdict(list), {}
  for n, [a, *b], c in d:
     _d[a].append((n, b, c))
  for a, b in _d.items():
     if (k:=[i for i in b if i[1]]):
        r['.'.join(p+[a])] = {**{i[0]:i[-1] for i in b if not i[1]}, **group(k, p+[a])}
     else:
        r[b[0][0]] = b[0][-1]
  return r
        
 
print(group([(a, a.split('.'), b) for a, b in data.items()]))
```

Output:

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': {'c': 2, 'c.1': 3}, 'd': {'d': 4, 'd.1': {'d.1': 5, 'd.1.2': 6}}}
```